# controll a pages responsive width size

Tags: laravel, vue.js, responsive-design, bootstrap-vue

I have a page that looks like this[image]

The width of the datetimepicker that you see on the picture cant get any smaller.
So what happends when the width is over 1200 px and under about 1550 px is that the datepicker goes outside of its place like this:

[image]

When the width is 1550 px or over the width is wide enough to fit the datetimepicker
And when the width is below 1200 the responsiveness kicks in and makes the page look good like this

[image]

So what i need help with is how to set for the responsiveness to kick in att 1550 instead of 1200. Is this possible, if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also fix overflow content like this

```css
.button-container {
     padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-box-align: baseline;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}



.button-container {
    max-width: 300px;
}


.button-wrapper {
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.button-wrapper button{
  padding:5px 15px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:10px;
}
.button-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
  height:8px;
}
button-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px grey; 
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.button-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ff9b51; 
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.button-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: gray; 
}
```

```html
<!-- Meta View Port -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  

<div class="button-container">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="btn-default">Range</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-default">Week</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-default">Month</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-default">Quarter</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-default">Year</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add custom 'breakpoints' to your css in the form of a media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1550px) {
  // type your styles here
  // set your content to be vertically aligned
}
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Okej good start. But i have no clue of how the css content would look like for my page to convert to responsive mode. what code can you make that says to the page to become responsive? and also can you do max width:1550 and min width 1200